# How can I test a model's custom predicate? (Ransack search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, search, minitest, ransack

I have a model called `Invoice` with an `amount_cents` attribute.

I'm using [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem to perform searching and want users to be able to search by integer amounts.

I added a custom predicate to my `Invoice` model to format the search params and multiply whatever the user enters in the search field by `100`. This way it will match values in the `amount_cents` column:

*Invoice model:*

```
  ransacker :integer_amount,
            type: :integer,
            formatter: proc { |amount| amount * 100 } do |amount|
    amount.table[:amount_cents]
  end
```

*form search fields:*

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.search_field :integer_amount_gt,
  class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="mx-1 form-group">
  <%= f.search_field :integer_amount_lt,
  class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

*Invoices controller action:*

```
def index
    @invoices = current_account.invoices.ransack(params[:q])
end
```

I'd like to test this, but from the **model's perspective**. So far I've written a controller test like so:

```
  test "integer_amount params should fetch right invoices" do
    invoice_within_range = invoices(:one) # amount_cents = 900
    invoice_outside_range = invoices(:two) # amount_cents = 10000

    get invoices_path, params: {
      q: {
        integer_amount_gt: "8",
        integer_amount_lt: "10",
      },
    }
    invoices = controller.view_assigns["invoices"]

    assert_includes invoices, invoice_within_range
    assert_not_includes invoices, invoice_outside_range
  end
```

I think this is sort of an *integration* test as the custom predicate is doing it's job correctly, but I don't think it's clean to test it this way as it's a model feature and not the controller's.

Is there a better way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to test the custom ransackers from the model's perspective. The integration tests are usually much slower.

Your test case could look like that (I'm not familiar with the `MiniTest` framework, so the test example might contain some errors):

```rb
test "integer_amount ransacker should fetch right invoices" do
  invoice_within_range = invoices(:one) # amount_cents = 900
  invoice_outside_range = invoices(:two) # amount_cents = 10000

  invoices = Invoice.ransack(
    integer_amount_gt: 8,
    integer_amount_lt: 10
  ).result

  assert_includes invoices, invoice_within_range
  assert_not_includes invoices, invoice_outside_range
end
```

There's also an alternative idea. Instead of creating test data in DB and fetching it you can test the Ransack generates the correct SQL query and includes the proper conditions:

```rb
test "integer_amount ransacker generates proper query" do
  query = Invoice.ransack(
    integer_amount_gt: 8,
    integer_amount_lt: 10
  ).result

  # test the query is correct and executed
  assert_empty query.to_a
  # test the query contains the proper SQL conditions
  assert_match /`invoices`.`amount_cents` > 800 AND `invoices`.`amount_cents` < 1000/, query.to_sql
end
```